# Stochastic process’ mean-square derivative $X'(t)\equiv 0$ implies $X(t) \equiv X$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Suppose $\{X(t),t\in T\}$ is a real-valued stochastic process, $\{X(t),t\in T\}$ is  mean-square differentiable on $T$ with its mean-square derivative $X'(t)=0$, prove that $X(t)=X$ where $X$ is some random variable.

I know it seems obvious but I failed to prove it. In real analysis, the similar conclusion can be proved using Lagrange's mean value theorem, however there is no corresponding theorem in a mean-square derivative fashion. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: What do you mean with $X'(t) = 0$? To have such equality I'd expect a term like a mean: $\mathbb{E}[X(t)]' = 0$

Comment: @clarkmaio It’s the mean-square derivative of $\{X(t),t\in T\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose without loss of generality that $X(0) = 0$.

Start by verifying that a mean-square differentiable process is mean-square continuous.

Set $f(t) = E[X(t)^2]$, so $f(0)=0$.  Note for any $t$ that
$$\begin{align*}\left|\frac{f(t+\epsilon) - f(t)}{\epsilon} \right|&= \left|E\left[\frac{X(t+\epsilon)^2 - X(t)^2}{\epsilon}\right]\right| \\
&= \left|E\left[\frac{X(t+\epsilon)-X(t)}{\epsilon} (X(t+\epsilon)+X(t))\right]\right| \\
&\le \sqrt{E\left[\left(\frac{X(t+\epsilon)-X(t)}{\epsilon} \right)^2\right]E\left[ (X(t+\epsilon)+X(t))^2\right]} \\
&\to \sqrt{E[X'(t)^2] \cdot E[(2 X(t))^2]} = 0
\end{align*}$$
as $\epsilon \to 0$, using mean-square differentiability and continuity.  Hence $f$ is differentiable with $f'(t) = 0$ for all $t$.  By the usual mean value theorem, $f(t) =0 $ for all $t$.  This is to say that $X(t) = 0$ almost surely, for every $t$.